# The repository is null when i call it from junit

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to create junit and i am trying to
call a service which inside himm calls a repository.
And this repositoty is null.
I first search and found that i need to include this annotations

```
@DataJpaTest 
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) 
@SpringBootTest(classes = CommonSubsequenceApplication.class).
```

But this takes me another error: found multiple declaration of @Bootsrap for test class.
And if i remove `@DataJpaTest` i don't have this error i get the one that i had before having anyone of this annotation .. repository is null.

```
    @DataJpaTest 
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) 
    @WebMvcTest(value = SubsequenceController.class)
    @SpringBootTest(classes = CommonSubsequenceApplication.class)
    class SubsequenceServiceTest {
        
        SubsequenceService subsequenceService = new SubsequenceService();
    
    
        @Test
        public void addSubsequenceTest8() throws Exception {
            assertEquals("Success", subsequenceService.addSubsequence("xenis",new Subsequence( 2l,"Xenis", "Learn to dance", "No subsequences", new Date(), 0)));
        }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you instantiate your `SubsequenceService` by yourself.

```
SubsequenceService subsequenceService = new SubsequenceService();
```

This way Spring has no chance to do the dependency injection.
Injecting the `SubsequenceService` itself could do the trick.

```
@Autowired
private SubsequenceService subsequenceService
```

---

### Edit

> ...now even the service isn't working, is null

Oh I see! This should be because of the `@DataJpaTest` and `@WebMvcTest` annotations. These annotations are test slices which reduce the amount of beans that are loaded into the `ApplicationContext`. Basically you say that you only want to load beans relevant to the web layer and the persistence Layer. This excludes all beans that are annotated with a simple `@Service`.
By Removing these two annotations on your test class all beans in your project should be loaded into the `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: thanks i really appreciate it, but now even the service isn't working, is null

Comment: @HerrArhone I edited my answer. Hope this will help you!

Comment: Well i seems to have figure out what is wrong , your responsed help but i had to add this also @SpringBootTest.